# If $f=g'$ for continuous $g$, then Fundamental Theorem of Calculus works

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, mean-value-theorem

If $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ and $f=g'$ on $(a,b)$ for some continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$, is it true $\int_a^bf(x)\hspace{0.1cm}dx=g(b)-g(a)$?

---

I tried to partition $[a,b]$ to $[a_0=a,a_1]\cup[a_1,a_2]\cup\dots$, where $f$ is discontinuous at $a_j$ and use mean value theorem on each sub-interval so $\int_{a_i}^{a_{i+1}} f(x)\hspace{0.1cm} dx=(a_{i+1}-a_i)g'(c_i)$ for $c_i\in(a_i,a_{i+1})$. But I have problem with the summation over all sub-intervals to get $g(b)-g(a)$. Should I refine the partition to get definition of Riemann integral?

Comment: This answered your question: [the continuity of the primitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435067/the-continuity-of-the-primitive) Since $F(x):=\int_c^xf$ (for some $c\in(a,b)$) is continuous on $[a,b]$ and coincides with $g(x)-g(c)$ on $(a,b)$, it also coincides at $a$ and $b.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\,f=g’\,$ on $\,(a,b)\,,\,$ it results that

$\displaystyle\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\delta}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\delta}g’(x)\,\mathrm dx=g(b-\delta)-g(a+\epsilon)$

for any $\,\epsilon,\delta\in\left(0,\dfrac{b-a}2\right).$

If you want to know why the previous equalities are true, see [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_second_part).

Moreover,

$\begin{align}\displaystyle\int_a^b\!f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0^+\\\delta\to0^+}\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\delta}\!\!f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0^+\\\delta\to0^+}\!\big[g(b-\delta)-g(a+\epsilon)\big]\!=\\[3pt]&=g(b)-g(a)\;,\end{align}$

indeed $\,g\,$ is continuous on $\,[a,b]\,.$

Comment: @AnneBauval, see [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_second_part)

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: I don't know who downvoted. I upvoted as soon as I understood, thanks to your comment.